# How can I back up a patched version of Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

As we all know, when you first install SC2, the are several updates/patches that comes along with it and it takes **aeons** to finish.

I'm wondering if there is a way to save the updates/patches and restore it later when I reformat my computer so that I don't have to go to all that manual updating again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite the patches, but you can backup the entire SC2 directory and simply copy it back after your format.

Comment: And it would work like newly installed?

Comment: Done it several times myself. Only thing I've noticed compared to a regular install is you don't have Start menu shortcuts.

Comment: @Dracs Do you backup C:\Users\Username\Documents\StarCraft II\ as well or just C:\Program Files (x86)\StarCraft II\ ?

Comment: @IMB I have before, but I don't usually. The folder in Documents contains your campaigns, saved games, replays custom map data. It will work fine with or without it.

Comment: If you are concerned about a backup folder copy not installing shortcuts etc, what you can do is install the base version from DVD/digital download, then copy the backed-up folder over the install folder. This will install shortcuts/registry entries, and then update the files.

Answer (score 2):

Blizzard support says [no](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/132033305#2), but you can still get it at [fileplanet](http://www.fileplanet.com/115362/0/section/Patches) :D

Answer (score 2):

Looks like patches are now available as [separate downloads](http://eu.battle.net/support/en/article/starcraft-ii-patch-information;jsessionid=2B12A43D914ED94603144C594BFD4857.blade07_06_bnet-support) from Blizzard.

So when you update Starcraft 2 you could manually download the patches and save them for later. Then when you need to restore/reinstall everything: install Starcraft 2 from DVD, then run the patches.

EDIT: My link is now broken.

Comment: Dead link now ...